# How to extract and set up several collection variables from a postman body

Tags: postman

I receive a body as

```
"items": [
    {
        "itemId": "0",
        "productId": "1e212fbf-cdf2-4b30-bd60-9f315f7e4dfa"
    },
    {
        "itemId": "1",
        "productId": "1e212fbf-cdf2-4b30-bd60-9f315f7e4dfa"
    },
    {
        "itemId": "2",
        "productId": "f2b5c9e9-9c79-4430-ade6-7211d6978a27"
    }
    {
        "itemId": "3",
        "productId": "cadace2b-156a-4740-9955-fc23cf6f93aa"
    }
]
```

I'd like to extract all productId and store them as a separate collectionVariables like

```
orderProductId1
orderProductId2
orderProductId3
```

I used

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("orderProductId1", jsonData.items[0].productId);      
pm.collectionVariables.set("orderProductId2", jsonData.items[1].productId);
```

I might receive a different number of itemId/ProductId, so I don't want to manually create required number of collectionVariables. I guess I need a loop?

How to create variables with different names?

I tried

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.items.length; i++) 
    {
    pm.collectionVariables.set("orderProductId[i]", jsonData.items[i].productId);     
    }
```

but it creates only one variable orderProductId[i] and not a orderProductId1, orderProductId2, orderProductId3.

Comment: Wouldn't ``orderProductId${i}`` work there. Surrounded in backticks. There are better more efficient ways at extracting those values and storing as a variable though.

Comment: Thank you!  It works.  But I will be very happy if you share other ways how to do it or point me to a relevant resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can find that property in the obj and set it to the collection variable with something like this:

```js
pm.response.json().items.find((obj, index) => { pm.collectionVariables.set(`productId_${index}`, obj.productId)})
```